# Script mode py3 and lack of output in s3 after successful training

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I've created a script where I define my Tensorflow Estimator, then I pass it to AWS sagemaker sdk and run fit(), the training passes (though doesnt show anything related to training in the console) and in S3 the only output is /source/sourcedir.tar.gz and I believe there also should be at least /model/model.tar.gz which for some reason is not generated and I'm not getting any errors.

```
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session()
role = get_execution_role()
inputs = sagemaker_session.upload_data(path='data', key_prefix='data/NamingConventions')
NamingConventions_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='NamingConventions.py',
                               role=role,
                               framework_version='1.12.0',
                               train_instance_count=1,
                               train_instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                               py_version='py3',
                               model_dir="s3://sagemaker-eu-west-2-218566301064/model")
NamingConventions_estimator.fit(inputs, run_tensorboard_locally=True)
```

and my model_fn from 'NamingConventions.py'

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    net = keras.layers.Embedding(alphabetLen + 1, 8, input_length=maxFeatureLen)(features[INPUT_TENSOR_NAME])
    net = keras.layers.LSTM(12)(net)

    logits = keras.layers.Dense(len(conventions), activation=tf.nn.softmax)(net) #output
    predictions = tf.reshape(logits, [-1])

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
            mode=mode,
            predictions={"ages": predictions},
            export_outputs={SIGNATURE_NAME: PredictOutput({"ages": predictions})})

    loss = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(labels, predictions)

    train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
        learning_rate=params["learning_rate"],
        optimizer="AdamOptimizer")

    predictions_dict = {"ages": predictions}

    eval_metric_ops = {
        "rmse": tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(
            tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions)
    }

    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

I still can't get it running, I'm trying to use script-mode, it seems like I can't import my model from the same directory.
Currently my script:

```
import argparse
import os

if __name__ =='__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # hyperparameters sent by the client are passed as command-line arguments to the script.
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', type=int, default=10)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.1)

    # input data and model directories
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TRAIN'))
    parser.add_argument('--test', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TEST'))

    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()

import tensorflow as tf
from NC_model import model_fn, train_input_fn, eval_input_fn

def train(args):
    print(args)
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn, model_dir=args.model_dir)
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(train_input_fn, max_steps=1000)
    eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn)
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the training job listed as successful in the AWS console? Did you check the training log in Amazon CloudWatch?

Comment: 2019-01-20 17:02:48,068 sagemaker-containers INFO Reporting training SUCCESS - the logs don't say anything else related to the training. I believe it must be due to me using 'script mode'.. aws documentation is really confusing, I'm still trying to get it work without making a script

Comment: I think I found your problem. In script mode, your training code needs to explicitly save the model (unlike in normal mode). SageMaker passes a '--model_dir' parameter that needs to by handled by your script. Here's an example: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart/tensorflow_script_mode_quickstart.ipynb

Comment: I've added what I wrote rn, still not working though... I've seen the example but it uses completely different structure to what AWS docs show and is fairly complex

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your estimator model_dir to the path in the environment variable SM_MODEL_DIR.

This is a bit contrary to the docs which are not clear on this point. I suspect the --model_dir arg is used for distributed training and not saving of the final artifact.

Note that you'll get all your checkpoints and summaries there to so it probably best to use --model_dir in your estimator and copy your model export to SM_MODEL_DIR when training has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Script mode gives you the freedom to write TensorFlow scripts the way you want, but the cost is, you have to do almost everything by yourself. For example, here in your case, if you want the model.tar.gz in S3, you have to export the model locally first. Then SageMaker will upload your local model to S3 automatically.

So what you need to add in your script is:

1. You need to add an exporter and pass it to eval_spec.
2. You need to call export_savedmodel to save the model to the local model dir that SageMaker can get. The local model dir is in env variable SM_MODEL_DIR, and should be '/opt/ml/model'.
3. To finish above, I guess you need to have your serving_input_fn implemented too.

Then SageMaker will upload your model from the local model dir automatically to the S3 model dir you specify. And you can see that in S3 after job succeeds.